# Получить список полей структуры и их значений

Tags: c#, структуры

Есть структура с кучей полей.

```
[System.SerializableAttribute]
public class RealCellCoord
{
    public int id;
    // cell number
    public int ncell;
    //  CoordX
    public uint X_StopBack;
    public uint X_StopForward;
    ...
}
```

Как получить список названий полей - способ вроде найден.

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memberlist = typeof(RealCellCoord).GetMembers();
for (int i = 0; i < memberlist.Length; i++)
{ 
    if(memberlist[i].MemberType == System.Reflection.MemberTypes.Field)
        if (memberlist[i].Name != "id")
        {
            ((DataRowView)bs_Coords.Current)[memberlist[i].Name] =
                RCC.GetType().GetProperty(memberlist[i].Name)
                             .GetValue(RCC, null);                          
        }
}
```

Но при попытке получить значение данного поля идет ошибка.

Comment: 1. Вы уверены, что вам не нужно воспользоваться ORM?
2. Какая ошибка? В какой строке? Если строка состоит из нескольких вызовов, какой из них завершается с ошибкой?

Comment: у вас в классе не Properties, а Fields

вываливается, скорее всего здесь: GetProperty(memberlist[i].Name)

Answer (score 4):

Рефлекшен это конечно иногда здорово, но только если у нас не осталось другого выбора. Если злоупотреблять таким проходом, то в дальнейшем можно получить крупные проблемы с архитектурой. Я бы посоветовал вам поменять поля на свойства и использовать `PropertyDescriptor`. Вот небольшой пример для вас:

```
public class RealCellCoord
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int Ncell { get; set; }

    public uint X_StopBack { get; set; }
    public uint X_StopForward { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RealCellCoord cord = new RealCellCoord();
        PropertyDescriptor descr = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(cord)["Id"];
        descr.SetValue(cord, 777);
        Console.WriteLine("cord.Id = " + cord.Id.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Если честно, ваш код не совсем понял, но надеюсь что подход, что я привёл, вам поможет.