# получить список значений полей элемена списка

Tags: c#, list, framework

всем добрый день!

есть задача:
[Получить список значений поля объектов класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866705/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

у меня обратный вопрос:
проект C#
есть класс

```
public class ClassA
{
public long ID {get; set;}
...
public double Value {get; set;}
...
public int LinkID {get; set;}
//МНОГО элементов
}
```

и есть список

```
List<ClassA> aList
```

командой

```
      var Colls = (from t in typeof(ClassA).GetProperties() select t.Name).ToList();
```

получаю наименование полей/столбцов/компонентов элемента списка

как мне в цикле получить все значения, скажем, 1-го элемента&
заранее спасибо

п.с. NetFrameWork 4.5

Comment: Уберите `.Name`, вам нужен объект свойства, а не просто текст с его именем. Дальше берете нужное свойство (прим: `Colls[0]`), вызываете у него метод `.GetValue()` в который передаете нужный объект из коллекции `aList`. В итоге получаете нечто такое: `var value = Colls[0].GetValue(aList[0])`, и будет вам значение первого свойства, первого объекта коллекции. Можете пойти дальше, написать например такое `var props = typeof(ClassA).GetProperties().Select(x => (Name: x.Name, Value: x.GetValue(classAInst)));`, где `classAInst` это инициализированный объект из коллекции, будут вам все свойства.

Comment: EvgeniyZ - огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

помогло
[Получить список полей структуры и их значений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/260530/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9?rq=1)

```
 PropertyDescriptor descr = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(EDBRecList[j])[Colls[0]];
 string x = descr.GetValue(EDBRecList[j]).ToString();
```